# How to transfer a joomla content to another server?

Tags: joomla-3.x, installation, akeebabackup

I recently set up a joomla site on `demojoomla.com` and started entering data to check a proof of concept.

Following that phase, I bought a hosting package at Strato.de where I am able to setup a joomla application with one click.

Although the demo site does not contain a huge amount of data, and in theory I could set it up again by hand, I would really like to transfer everything automatically.

I have made a backup using `Akeeba` but am not sure if I can just copy it into the new joomla site and restore it there.

I tried using kickstart.php but that failed due to missing MySQL configuration. I have no idea what I could do to fix that.

What is the best approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any data created in Joomla is stored in the database. This means that when taking a backup using Akeeba, you **must** also take a backup of the database, else, you're only restoring the files, without the content.

The backup file (JPA file) will contain the entire Joomla CMS + any install extensions + the database. Therefore on your new hosting provider, *you do not need to install Joomla using the 1 click feature*.

You will need to ensure that your destination server is set-up properly to install Joomla, including setting up a database.

Simply upload the JPA file and kickstart to the directory of your choice, then run the restoration process.

As part of the restoration process, the installer will ask you for the new database information.

Comment: So, backup database, backup files, restore database, restore files. Right? What about database connections? Where are they defined? They will presumably be different on the 2 systems...

Comment: The JPA backup file that you download, will contain **everything**. Before restoring it, you need to create a new database and a database username. When restoring your backup, you will need to enter these details. Other than that, everything is completely automated. It's exactly the same process as manually installing Joomla, but just with a backup instead

Comment: ok. Beginning to understand. When I create a database, I just need the database name and a user. The tables etc will be created by the restore. Is there anything else I need to be aware of. e.g. user privileges...

Comment: In regards to privileges, you will need to assign your newly created database username to the actual database. And then yes, all tables etc are created and populated automatically

Comment: it works. I was missing the step of creating the database on the new server.

Answer (score 4):

As @lodder says, the JPA file generated by Akeeba Backup contains everything you need (files and database, including Joomla itself), so all you need to do is upload the JPA file and kickstart.php to your server and visit "http://yourdomain.com/kickstart.php" (if you're using Kickstart pro, you'll have to rename the file to something else first).

But since you mention a missing MySQL error, I'd like to add some notes regarding the database restoration, as this part can be confusing sometimes. The [Kickstart documentation](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/troubleshooter/abidatabase.html) explains this quite detailed.

The error message is most likely because you didn't enter the correct database information in the dialog box. [This page](http://www.strato-faq.co.uk/article/567/This-is-how-you-use-the-MySQL-Database.html) has some information on how to set up a database on strato.de

A couple of things to remember:

1. You must create the database on your new host. Joomla and Akeeba Backup cannot create the database for you.
2. During the restoration process, you must provide the details for your new database, *not* from your original site.